# Assembly memory addressing in big endian format

Tags: memory, assembly, arm

Kinda stuck here and was hoping for a pointer on memory addressing.

[image]

In theory, these represent R1 through R4. I assume 0x60 is R1, and 0x6C is R4, incrementing by a word each time. Is that the case?

If I wanted to run

```
 ADD R1, R2
```

Would it store the result of the addition of 0x60 and 0x6C in memory location 0x60? Or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of the figure is right.  Where did you get it?

Comment: @zwol that is very possible. I am taking a class in assembly, however the teacher barely speaks english, so most of us are using the arm docs at http://infocenter.arm.com/ to try to self-teach and decypher the assignments. However, I'm not looking for someone to do my homework for me, only a decyphering of memory addressing. here is the actual problem I'm trying to apply this to: http://i.imgur.com/xkFXRTG.png EDIT: Rereading it while I upload it, I now see that they provided R1-R4. Just- also that chart. Maybe I need to dive deeper into the docs here.

Comment: Just don't read anything about ARMv6 and later, which have a _different_ big-endian format. That example is clearly talking about the crazy old word-invariant BE-32 one, not the new (somewhat saner) BE-8.

Comment: @Notlikethat Everything I learn about this class gives me existential dread. I'll stick to- whatever old documentation I can find, then!

Comment: Your edit turned the question into nonsense, and invalidated the answer which talks about the diagram.  The diagram is key to your question / misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARM registers do **not** correspond to any memory location.  In some contexts ("spill slots" on the stack, "task state" used for multitasking) there will be memory locations reserved to save the contents of some or all registers, but they must be explicitly copied back and forth.

The problem you're trying to do is poorly worded, but I *think* the table gives the values of *memory locations* 0x60 through 0x6C, and, separately, the *text* ("[R1] = ..., [R2] = ..., etc") gives the values of the registers.  If I'm reading this right, the instruction labeled (a) will copy the *low byte* of the value at memory location 0x62, which is either 0x9A or 0x90, I'm not sure which, into register R1, sign-extending it.  I hope that's enough to get you unstuck.

Comment: That helped a lot. That should hopefully give me a start to getting something resembling correct answers here. Thanks!

Comment: @RNPF you may try to search for some kid book about computers from 1985-1995, it will probably explain old simple CPU <-> bus <-> memory / peripherals architecture in simple way. Once you realize the memory is completely different chip from CPU, it will make lot more sense, why CPU has temporary value holders "registers" (fast, but few), and why memory has addresses to address particular content cell (slow, but big and universal).